# Line height changed when using new flutter sdk with material3

Tags: flutter, material3

I have updated the flutter sdk and the layouts were broken.
When using the flag

```
useMaterial3: false,
```

everything seems fine but the line height of texts is to height.
Changing the line heights in the textStyles to

```
heightFactor: .9
```

makes everything look like before.

But - has the linespacing/heightFactor changed in material3 or am I doing something wrong?